# What does the Clown Makeup mean by "something else"?

Tags: river-city-girls-2

The description for the Clown Makeup says "*Refills Guard Break much faster, and something else*". What does the "something else" refer to?

[image: Clown Makeup description]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several attack sound effects are replaced by clown noises when wearing Clown Makeup.